# c:forEach doesn't render inside rich:dataTable

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces, jstl

I am using c:forEach inside rich:dataTable. But c:forEach doesn't substitute the values for answer.choices variable and hence nothing is rendered. Is it wrong to use c:forEach inside a rich:dataTable?

Comment: Similar question and answer from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151476/backing-bean-string-access-in-jsf/2154159#2154159

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't work - don't use JSTL tags inside UI iteration components (`dataTable`, for example).

Use [`<ui:repeat>`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/facelets/10-TagReference/facelets-ui-repeat.html) or [`<a4j:repeat>`](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_repeat.html) instead of `<c:forEach>` to iterate inside a `dataTable`

The signature of these tags is a little different:

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
   <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
</a4j:repeat>
```

Comment: @Bozho Good to know (+1). But where should i avoid to use JSTL in Java Server Faces ?

Comment: From JSTL only the `functions` taglib is actually useful in JSF. The JSTL `core` and `fmt` taglibs are superfluous in JSF as JSF at its own already has ways to do the same. Further the JSTL `xml` and `sql` taglibs are intented for quick prototyping only and have no business value.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of compile-time vs. render-time tags in jsf. It's the key to understanding the reason why this combination can't work.